# Bad reading number with digit using ReactJS, NVDA and FireFox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, nvda

I write application with accessibility using ReactJS.

I have a problem with NVDA and FireFox - NVDA can't read number correctly.

I've found solution (use setTimeout with 0 delay), but I think, that can do it better.

I've created proof of concept to show the problem:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
function generateRandomNumber(min = 0, max = 9, toFixed = 2) {
  const number = (Math.random() * (max - min) + min).toFixed(toFixed);
  return number;
};

function getRandomNumber(min = 0, max = 9, toFixed = 2) {
  return generateRandomNumber(101, 400, 2);
};

class Work extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      number: 0,
      showElement: true
    };
  }

  randomNumber() {
    this.setState({
      showElement: false,
      number: getRandomNumber()
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        showElement: true
      });
    }, 0);
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div aria-live="polite">
          {this.state.showElement &&
          <p>{this.state.number}</p>}
        </div>
        <button onClick={() => this.randomNumber()}>Random me!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class NotWork extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      number: 0
    };
  }


  randomNumber() {
    this.setState({
      number: getRandomNumber()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div aria-live="polite">
          <p>{this.state.number}</p>
        </div>
        <button onClick={() => this.randomNumber()}>Random me!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}




class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <div aria-live="polite">
            <h3>Works example:</h3>
            <Work />
            <hr />
            <h3>Not works example:</h3>
            <NotWork />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

    React.render( < App / > ,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

JSFiddle for run:

https://jsfiddle.net/IceManSpy/1bxu6aau/1/

**To reproduce - sad path:**

- Run jsfiddle on FireFox
- Run NVDA (you can open speech viewer)
- Click sometimes on Random me! in Not works example
- Check results - first value will be ok, but next not.
- Sometimes will be (fe. 345.67):

  - 345
  - 67
- but sometimes (it missing first digit):

  - 45
  - 67

**To reproduce - happy path:**

- Run jsfiddle on FireFox
- Run NVDA (you can open speech viewer)
- Click sometimes on Random me! in Works example
- Check results - every value will be ok.

**How can I resolve this problem without setTimeout ?**